# Writing custom converter in RCTConvert

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, mapkit, react-native-maps

I have successfully created RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY for primitive types like float and BOOL but cannot get my custom struct to work, I keep getting (null) from JavaScript.

I have defined my RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY in AIRMapMarkerManager.m

```
#import "RCTConvert+MoreMapKit.h"

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(importantStatus, ImportantStatus)
```

And in RCTConvert+MoreMapKit.m I have created my custom converter

```
+ (ImportantStatus)ImportantStatus:(id)json
{
    json = [self NSDictionary:json];
    NSLog(@"json @%", json); // returns (null)
    return (ImportantStatus){
        [self BOOL:json[@"isImportant"]],
        [self float:json[@"unimportantOpacity"]]
    };
}
```

RCTConvert+MoreMapKit.h

```
+ (ImportantStatus)ImportantStatus:(id)json;
```

AirMapMarker.h

```
struct ImportantStatus {
    BOOL isImportant;
    float unimportantOpacity;
};
typedef struct ImportantStatus ImportantStatus;

@property (nonatomic, assign) ImportantStatus importantStatus;
```

MapMarker.js

```
importantStatus: PropTypes.shape({
    isImportant: PropTypes.bool,
    unimportantOpacity: PropTypes.number,
}),
```

My JS code sending the data

```
<MapView.Marker
     coordinate={{
         latitude: this.props.latitude,
         longitude: this.props.longitude,
     }}
     importantStatus={{
         isImportant: false,
         unimportantOpacity: 0.5,
     }}
     // isImportant: false
     // unimportantOpacity: 0.5
>
</MapView.Marker>
```

When I just sent them as simple props as commented out above I got it working without using any custom converter function in RCTConvert+MoreMapKit.m so Im guessing that's where I have done something wrong.